# Troubleshooting extra spaces

Tags: spacing

My document has lots of extra whitespace appearing between various elements. The problems appear around one macro which appears multiple times. After every line in the macro, I've placed `%`'s, however, extra white spaces are still appearing.

- What method can I use to track what is causing these white spaces?
- Is it possible that items such as `ifstrequal` (from `etoolbox`), macros referenced inside macros,  mathmode-textmode switching, glossary entries, `\pageref`'s and other cross-referencing and labeling commands. or indented space before code will cause these problems?

Comment: Since you already added the `%` after each line in the macro (assuming with no spaces before that), without a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates this it is going to be difficult to help.

Comment: There's a nice page about unwanted space at [KOMA-Script homepage](http://www.komascript.de/signifikanteLeerzeichen). Unfortunately it is in German. Maybe someone who understands German and is better in English than me would translate it?

Comment: Ok, I've tried to translate it myself. Maybe someone could improve it.

Comment: While a spurious space *may* be caused by a bad definition is a package (one was discovered a few months ago in a very obscure corner of **babel**), the cause is probably our own macro writing or *usage*. A minimal example of both is necessary to diagnose the problem, if the advices in the given answer don't solve it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Scanner and parser for TeX are closely linked. If we assume that all characters have their usual catcode, then note:

- Line endings are treated as spaces.
- Multiple consecutive spaces are combined into one.
- Multiple consecutive blank lines are interpreted as paragraph end (like `\par`).
- Spaces following numbers that are read as numbers, will be interpreted as the end of the number and therefore ignored at output. This seldom affects normal LaTeX code, because in LaTeX `\setcounter`, `\addtocounter`, `\value`, `\roman`, `\Roman`, `\arabic`, `\Alph` and `\the` should be used to handle counters and their values.
- Spaces behind a macro are interpreted as the end of the macro (example: `\normalsize \normalfont` is the same like `\normalsize\normalfont` without space between `\normalsize` and `\normalfont`).
- Non-letters immediately following a macro are interpreted as the end of the macro too, but will be interpreted (example: `\normalsize9` will be interpreted like `\normalsize` and `9`, `\textbf9` is interpreted as `\textbf` with argument `9` and therefor will result in a bold 9, and `\textbf98` will be interpreted as `\textbf` with argument `9` followed by `8` and will result in a bold 9 followed by a nonbold 8).
- Except inside the code of classes and packages and between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` character `@` if a non-letter.
- Argument parentheses are non-letters!.
- Spaces between the closing and the opening bracket of macro argument will be ignored (e.g. `\stackrel{a}  {b}` is same like `\stackrel{a}{b}`).
- Spaces between group brackets are not ignored (in horizontal mode).
- Spaces after optional arguments (e.g. after `\section[foo]`) or optional stars off macros (e.g. after `\section*`) are ignored.
- LaTeX defines some statements to attempt to summarize spaces before and after the instruction (for example, `\index{foo}`). That does not always work.
- LaTeX defines some environments with ignoring spaces immediate after the environment. This usually applies to those environments, that switch into vertical mode (ie in particular not for `tabular` and `minipage` that will used to set vertical material in horizontal mode) like `verbatim`.

This means for example that with a macro like this:

```
\newcommand*{\Beispiel}[1]{
  { \sffamily{ \bfseries
      #1}
  }
}
```

three significant spaces will be set before and two after the argument.

Just for better illustration here the same definition again, but I've replaced the significant spaces by `\` and the line endings, which are significant spaces too, by `¶`:

```
\newcommand*{\Beispiel}[1]{¶
  {\ \sffamily{\ \bfseries
      #1}¶
  }¶
}
```

To remove these spaces you have simply omit some of them and comment out the other:

```
\newcommand*{\Beispiel}[1]{%
  {\sffamily{\bfseries
      #1}%
  }%
}
```

That's it almost. The last thing to mention is that a horizontal shift to the right of an entire block, such as a `tabular`, `\parbox` or a `minipage` sometimes is caused simply by the normal paragraph indentation. This's always the case if that block is at the beginning of the paragraph or a stand alone paragraph. In this case, a simple solution may be to but `\noindent` at the beginning of the paragraph (e.g. before the `\begin{tabular}`).